# Account Type Checking/Savings Disappears when making a contribution

Tags: fields, missing

Civi 4.7.17
WordPress 4.7.3
iATS Payments Processor

We recently upgraded from 4.6.26 to 4.7.17, since the upgrade this quirk has popped up. When making an ACH contribution, one of the required fields is Account Type and our two choices are Checking or Savings. This field displays with the drop-downs on initial load. However, once you select Electronic Funds Transfer, the Account Type field disappears. When you hit Confirm Contribution, you get an error telling you "you skipped a required field." This time the Field is displayed adn you can complete the donation.  I have attached several screenshots.

I tried changing the default to Credit Card but you get the same results.
I tried switching my theme to see if it was a theme conflict, but I get the same results.
I also used the Chrome Inspector adn found that it is not a CSS issue. It is missing HTML so likely a php issue.
I could not get the demo site to display an ACH payment option to test it there.

Is this a Civi core problem or an iATS Extension problem? Who generates the contribution form? Any ideas on what I can do to correct the issue?
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the xml file specifies that iATS 1.5.3 is **compatible with** CiviCRM 4.6. You must use 1.6.x with CiviCRM 4.7.

Comment: Hi Carl - can you please accept as answer so that we don't have this question automatically reposting to the still open questions page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We recently upgraded the iATS Payments extension to 1.6 and the problem went away.